# Link that passes parameters to Controller function

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model-view-controller

I currently have a view that is shared by two controller functions that pass in correct variables so i know where it is coming from.

I have a situation where I need URL references that can be clicked by the user that point to a function in both controllers that queries a Model and gets all the data from that model.

I am looking for some pointers on how to handle passing 2 parameters to the controller based on what the user clicked. I will post code to make this more understandable. Also, if I have a function that is querying the entire database, how can I use Query Scopes, so that if these parameters are passed to it, it doesnt query the entire database but instead uses my query scopes.

Here is the code for reference:

the View: http://pastebin.com/dWCEKztS

one of the controllers that I am working on first. The function that queries all of the rows of that Model: http://pastebin.com/LUbMLajs

In the Model, I tried to create these Query Scopes: http://pastebin.com/s30saqBL

So basically in the view, it displays certain names, and corresponding counts for each status. I have this all taken care of in that $totalCount data structure. I need to pass these to the index function so I can query only that certain data based off those parameters. The admin is in another table called admin, and in the advertiser application table there is an assigned_to field that links with that admin ID.

Please let me know if I need to clarify anything further!

Thanks

Comment: Please include the relevant code snippets as part of the question, don't link to outside URLs because they may become unavailable over time.

Comment: There is nothing here that is querying your entire database and if there was, query scopes wouldn't help.  They are there simply to make your where statements read more like human language.  The SQL generated in the end is all the same.

Answer (score 2):

Set the URL to pass variable with it, in your route.

```
route::get('/pageName/{variableName}', array('as' => 'page-name', 'uses' => 'yourControllerName@functionName'));
```

in controller:

```
public function functionName($variableName){

$get = Model::where('columnName', $variableName)->first();
}
```

Hope this help.